# Retrieve Dynamic select dropdown

Tags: php

I want to know what the user has selected in the both of the select boxes when I click submit.
but Iam unable to echo the selected values in POST['submit']. Here is the code I tried.

Could anyone suggest me: how to echo the selected values when submit.

```
<?php
    require 'init.php';

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
       foreach($_POST['role'] AS $ID => $Value)
       {
          $role = $Value;  //echo $letter.'<br>';
          $user = $_POST['user'][$ID]; //echo $serial.'<br>';

          echo $user.'<br>';
          echo $role;
       }
    }
    else 
    echo 'error';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php echo _SITE_LANGUAGE ?>">

    <body>  
      <?php
                      echo '<form action="" method="post">';
                      echo 'Select a role: 
                            <select name="role">';
                                $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM boolean_role WHERE role_id>2');
                                $query->execute();
                                echo '<option selected="selected">Choose a role </option>';                                
                                while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
                                {
                                   echo '<option value='.$row['role_id'].'>'.$row['role_name'].'</option>';           
                                }
                      echo '</select><br>';

                      echo 'Select an user: 
                            <select name="user">';
                                $query1 = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM boolean_users');
                                $query1->execute();
                                echo '<option selected="selected">Choose a user </option>';                                
                                while ($row = $query1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
                                {
                                  echo '<option value='.$row['id'].'>'.$row['username'].'</option>';          
                                }
                      echo '</select><br>';
                      echo '<input type="submit" value="submit">';
                      echo '</form>';

               ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just use `$user = $_POST['user'];` and `$role = $_POST['role'];` ?

Comment: It displaying me the error

Comment: Is there any other way to echo selected values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a foreach loop.

```
<?php
    require 'init.php';

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
       $user = $_POST['user'];
       $role = $_POST['role'];
       echo $user;
       echo $role;

    }
    else 
    echo 'error';
?>
```

Comment: I tried this way by removing foreach loop, it displays error

Comment: Try to use double quotes in your select form: `<option id="1">testvalue</option>`

Comment: It is going to the else statement with echo as error